# Spring Rest service getting encoded request parameter

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, encoding, escaping

I am facing an issue where url sent to spring rest service containing parameter "xyz=abc & amp ;emailDate=2014-09-09"

This URL is hit from emails sent to the customer. And when customer hits the URL some browser client on user's mobile is not converting "& amp ;" to &.

Please ignore spaces above. Stackoverflow is converting & amp ; to & if there are no spaces.

When request comes to server we see emailDate as null. Server side code is as below.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/openEmail", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody byte[] openEmail(RequestParam(value="token",  required=false) String customerToken, @RequestParam(value="emailDate", required=false) String emailDate, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException{
```

Can you please help me overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you set URIEncoding="UTF-8" in your server.xml ( if its tomcat ). More details here [Get Parameter Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445990/get-parameter-encoding)