# Why Do I get Entity &amp; in url formed with spring:url

Tags: spring-mvc

I am working with Spring MVC and I need to create a url with two parameters:

```
<spring:url value="/test" var="myUrl" >
  <spring:param name="param1" value="1" />
  <spring:param name="param2" value="2" />
</spring:url>
```

I get this: myUrl = /test?param1=1&amp ;param2=2 (note that this url have a entity &amp ; inside)
and when I put this url in a href=${myUrl} this don't work like I want.

Though, If I use c:url and c:param I get that I want :

```
<c:url value="/test" var="myUrl">
    <c:param name="param1" value="1" />
    <c:param name="param2" value="2" />
</c:url>
```

myUrl = /test?param1=1&param2=2

What is the problem with "spring:param" ? Do I need to configure some parameter in my Spring mvc configuration?

Thanks.

Comment: Please check if you set URIEncoding="UTF-8" in your server.xml ( if its tomcat ). More details here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445990/get-parameter-encoding

Comment: Thanks lateralus, adding a URIEncoding="UTF-8" attribute to the tomcat http connector, all work fine now.