# Currency Symbols like €,£ are Corrupted in Spring HTTP.GET

Tags: java, rest, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I have a simple rest endpoint like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/currencyCode")
public ResponseEntity<String> dummyEndpoint(@RequestParam("currencyCode") String currencyCode) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(currencyCode, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

But when I call this with this `http://localhost:8080/currencyCode?currencyCode=£` or this `http://localhost:8080/currencyCode?currencyCode=€`, I get those responses: `Â£` and `â‚¬`. But for Dollar sign($), it works.

What should I do to get correct symbol using `org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam`?

EDIT: I have tried what @f1sh [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37928309/currency-symbols-like-%E2%82%AC-%C2%A3-are-corrupted-in-spring-http-get?noredirect=1#comment63307440_37928309), but I still have same problem.

`((SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper) request).getRequest().getParameterMap().get("currencyCode")` returns `â¬` still.

EDIT-2:
I have 2 Connectors in my server.xml. They are like this:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

and

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

I am using apache-tomcat-7.0.67 by the way.

Thanks...

Comment: @f1sh, I have updated the question. Thanks though.

Comment: How did you make these requests? These symbols must be URL-encoded before transmission and if a correctly-implemented client made the request, it should also have sent the correct content-encoding header

Comment: We're talking about this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445990/get-parameter-encoding right? Where this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5501932/1743880 is recommending to set the URI encoding?

Comment: Yes @Tunaki, and I am trying to say that **it doesn't work for me**. If you have any other solution, I'll be glad to hear.

Comment: @billc.cn, I used browser and this request is going to be made by a 3rd party library. We were using Thrift before and it was working with those symbols, hence encoding beforehand doesn't seem to be an option. Thanks.