# Passing Japanese characters in a HTTP GET request

Tags: java, spring, rest, character-encoding

I have a Spring Application on the server side.

When I hit the following url:

[http://127.0.0.1:8080/processToken?token=Akカ](http://127.0.0.1:8080/processToken?token=Ak%E3%82%AB)

On the server side the token is interpreted as

> Akã«

What type of Encoding should I follow so that is interpreted correctly and also should where exactly should the encoding be done?

I tried this in [POSTMAN](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) with the Header attribute set as the following:

```
Content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
```

However, it is still producing the same result.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928046/spring-mvc-utf-8-encoding

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445990/get-parameter-encoding

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring MVC UTF-8 Encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928046/spring-mvc-utf-8-encoding)