# How to bring special characters with angular 1.6 and RestController (spring)?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, rest

Hello to the community I commented that I am using angular 1.6, and I am sending a json with special characters (**ñ, é**), but when checking in the controller I get distorted.

**service - angular**

```
var json_ins = { ... } ; // special characters
var data = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(json_ins));
$http.get(VAR_CONTEXT+'/team/update?data=' + data).then(
    function (response) {
        deferred.resolve(response);
    },
    function (errResponse) {
        console.error('Error: Service Users');
        deferred.reject(errResponse);
    }
);
```

**RestController**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/team/update", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String update(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @QueryParam("data") String data) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
    JsonObject jResponse = new JsonObject();
    boolean success = true;
    try {
        Type detInscripcionType = new TypeToken<DetInscripcion>() {}.getType();
        DetInscripcion detInscripcion = new Gson().fromJson(data, detInscripcionType);            
        IntegranteBean integranteBean = inscripcionService.updateDetInscripcion(detInscripcion);            
        JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) jsonParser.parse(gson.toJson(integranteBean));
        jResponse.add("data", jsonObject);            
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        success = false;
        jResponse.addProperty("message", "Error de Conexion.");
    }
    jResponse.addProperty("success", success);
    return new Gson().toJson(jResponse);
}
```

I hope you can help me, since by checking the variable **data**, the special character comes to me distorted.

Comment: See if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445990/get-parameter-encoding

Answer (score 0):

Use `@RequestParam` instead of`@QueryParam`.